# Developing predictive model with labels that are known to contain some level of error and the goal is to correct erroneous labels

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, modeling

Is there a specific body of research or term for this type of problem? It feels different enough from the standard predictive model framework that there may be, but I can't remember discussing anything like it in grad school.

So again, building a predictive model to predict a target label A, but in the training data and population as a whole A is known to be accurate X% of the time. X is assumed to be high enough such that the model would actually hold real predictive utility. The whole point of the model is to predict A such that incorrect instances can be corrected. We are predicting using features B, C, D, none of which are directly related to the target label A.

Basically using predictions for anomaly detection, but again just curious if this is a standard problem setup that I've just missed in my schooling and work thus far. I've been searching for a few hours now but it's difficult to succinctly describe the problem especially if I am missing some key terminology. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Measurement error models might be what you are looking for. Very common in Bayesian approaches. The basic idea is that you treat the true label as an unobserved parameter. I found a non-Bayesian Python package that you might want to check out called cleanlab. The corresponding paper is [here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.00068) I skimmed through the paper and it seems to formulate the problem in a similar fashion as fully Bayes measurement error models.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe "weakly supervised learning" or"data driven ai" "data centric ai" as some buzzwords to look into, look at the snorkel library.

Comment: Thank you both! Really appreciate the paper link that is helpful.